# Trying to install ubuntu on XPS 15

Tags: 16.04, xps, rufus

I get error:

[image]

Booted on the usb key 16.04 LTS installed with Rufus... I don't know what wrong I am doing (BIOS option?)

Answer (score 0):

Those errors suggest that the graphics driver (in this case the native Nouveau driver) is causing the kernel (NMI) watchdog to throw those `stuck` messages.

You might want to try temporarily disabling the driver, or choosing a different driver (either different release or an Nvidia driver). I'd opt for the former to try to exempt the graphics driver from the problem entirely.

I should add that I run Ubuntu 17.10 on an XPS 15 (9560), and I'm pretty sure you have an onboard Intel HD Graphics chipset, so you might want to get spun up on that first, and then introduce the Nvidia driver when your system is stable.